# how to resolve 'pyResMan' installation error

Tags: python

## I have tried to install 'pyResMan' but found below errors,

C:\Users>pip install pyResMan
Collecting pyResMan
Using cached pyResMan-5.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: peppercorn in d:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyResMan) (0.6)
Collecting pyGlobalPlatform
Using cached pyGlobalPlatform-1.4.16.zip (18 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyscard in d:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyResMan) (2.0.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyGlobalPlatform
Building wheel for pyGlobalPlatform (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [11 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
copying pyGlobalPlatform\globalplatformlib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
copying pyGlobalPlatform_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
running build_ext
building 'pyGlobalPlatform.pyGlobalPlatform' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyGlobalPlatform
Running setup.py clean for pyGlobalPlatform
Failed to build pyGlobalPlatform
Installing collected packages: pyGlobalPlatform, pyResMan
Running setup.py install for pyGlobalPlatform ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pyGlobalPlatform did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [13 lines of output]
running install
D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
copying pyGlobalPlatform\globalplatformlib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
copying pyGlobalPlatform_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\pyGlobalPlatform
running build_ext
building 'pyGlobalPlatform.pyGlobalPlatform' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyGlobalPlatform

## note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Could anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you- you need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater

````
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/```
````